# how does a UIGestureRecognizer get its locationInView inside a scrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

We had some consultants build some code for us and the way they have it laid out is there is a UIScrollView, and a UIView inside it.

There is another UIView icon that gets added as a subview to the scrollView based on a selection in a table.  When this icon gets selected a popover is presented.  In the present popover code, they use the gesture's view to calculate the frame and where to present the popover.

Now I'm tasked to present the popover with a selection in the table.  When the zoom is = 1, that's pretty easy.  I just grab the size of the UIScrollView, calculate where I add the icon, then present the view from that icon.

When I do it at a different zoom level though, my code falls apart since I don't know exactly where I am in the scrollView.  I log the consultant's gesture from their method and they'll get origin.y position's of 5000.  That's why I'm asking on how the locationInView works inside a scrollView to try to figure out where I am in the yPosition to present my popover from the right place.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    id targetView = [sender view];
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.scrollView];
    NSLog(@"point: %f %f", point.x, point.y);
```